# How to properly serialize and deserialize versioned transaction

Tags: solana-program, solana-cli, web3.js

I am trying to add an instruction to a versioned transaction, After adding it i want that to be serialized and passed to the client for signing but while deserializing it throws an error mentioning `Expected signatures length to be equal to the number of required signatures` in legacy transaction version there is an option to bypass `verifySignature` and `requireAllSignatures` using `SerializeConfig` while serializing the transaction, is there any way to do that in versioned transaction

This is my sample code

```
 // deserialize the transaction
            const swapTransactionBuf = Buffer.from(swapInstruction, 'base64');
            const transaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(swapTransactionBuf);
            //get address lookup table accounts
            const addressLookupTableAccounts = await Promise.all(
              transaction.message.addressTableLookups.map(async lookup => {
                return new AddressLookupTableAccount({
                  key: lookup.accountKey,
                  state: AddressLookupTableAccount.deserialize(
                    //@ts-ignore
                    await connection.getAccountInfo(lookup.accountKey).then(res => res.data)
                  ),
                });
              })
            );
            const message = TransactionMessage.decompile(transaction.message, {
              addressLookupTableAccounts: addressLookupTableAccounts,
            });
            //test
            // construct the transfer instruction
            message.instructions.unshift(tokenClaimTransaction);
            message.payerKey = new PublicKey(parsedSwapClaimParams.targetAddress);
            message.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
            transaction.message = message.compileToV0Message(addressLookupTableAccounts);
            swapInstruction2 = bs58.encode(transaction.serialize());
```

In the client side

```
  const swapTransactionBuf = Buffer.from(
      swapInstruction2,
      'base64'
    )
    const _versionedTransaction =
      VersionedTransaction.deserialize(swapTransactionBuf)
```

getting `Expected signatures length to be equal to the number of required signatures` while deserializing

Comment: Have you tried base64 instead of base58 while encoding?

Answer (score 3):

The problem was with serializing `const serialized = Buffer.from(transaction.serialize()).toString('base64');`   is the correct way to serialize , and for partial signing `transaction.sign([Signer])` before serializing